# how to copy from char pointer one to anothe char pointer and add chars between

Tags: c, char, copy, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

i want to write function in c that gets char pointer with sentence inside, and in every place there is comma ',' i want to add space ' ' after the comma
i write this function

```
char* add_space_after_comma(char* textArr){
char* newText=(char *)malloc(strlen(textArr) * sizeof(textArr));
char* temp = newText;
int i;    
int indexNew=0;
int maxSize = strlen(textArr)-1;
if(newText  == NULL) 
    {
        printf("memory allocation failed \n");
        exit(0);    
    }
for (i = 0; textArr[i] != '\0'; i++, indexNew++) {
        if(indexNew == maxSize-1){
        
                temp = (char*)realloc(newText, maxSize*ARR_SIZE*sizeof(char));

                if(temp == NULL)
                {
                    printf("memory allocation failed \n");
                    exit(0);
                }
            maxSize= maxSize * ARR_SIZE;
            newText =temp;
        }
        newText[indexNew] = textArr[i];
        if(textArr[i] == ','){
        indexNew++;
        newText[indexNew] = ' ';
        }
    }
indexNew++;
newText[indexNew] = '\0';

printf("\nthe new text is: %s\n", newText);
return (char*)newText;
}
```

but when im trying to run and check it, its print to the screen

**the new text is: �����T$
�v���넍�&**

how can i write this function rigth?

Comment: Why not count the number of commas in the original string and allocate `strlen(s) + commas + 1` bytes? That would avoid re-allocation. (Frankly, the allocation code looks a bit fishy.)

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function parameter should be declared with the qualifier `cosnt` because the passed string is not changed within the function. The function creates a new string based on the content of the source string.

```
char * add_space_after_comma( const char* textArr );
```

The memory allocation in this declaration

```
char* newText=(char *)malloc(strlen(textArr) * sizeof(textArr));
```

is equivalent to

```
char* newText=(char *)malloc(strlen(textArr) * sizeof( char * ));
```

and evidently does not make a sense.

The memory reallocation

```
temp = (char*)realloc(newText, maxSize*ARR_SIZE*sizeof(char));
```

is inefficient and also does  not make a sense. You need at first to count occurrences of the comma and then at once to allocate an array with the required size.

This incrementing of the index after the for loop

```
indexNew++;
```

is wrong. You need to remove this statement.

And you need to be sure that the passed pointer is indeed points to a string.

The function can be declared and defined as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * add_space_after_comma( const char* textArr )
{
    const char c = ',';

    size_t count = 0;

    for ( const char *p = textArr; ( p = strchr( p, c ) ) != NULL; ++p )
    {
        ++count;
    }

    char *result = malloc( strlen( textArr ) + 1 + count );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        char *t = result;
        for ( const char *p; ( p = strchr( textArr, c ) ) != NULL; textArr = p + 1 )
        {
            size_t n = p - textArr + 1;
            memcpy( t, textArr, n );
            t[n++] = ' ';
            t +=n;
        }

        strcpy( t, textArr );
    }

    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    const char *textArr = "1,2,3,4,5";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", textArr );

    char *result = add_space_after_comma( textArr );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\"\n", result );
    }

    free( result );
}
```

The program output is

```
"1,2,3,4,5"
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Like pointed out in the comments, if you count the target-character in input string once, all you need is one `malloc()` for the result. One time parsing of string is efficient than a series of `realloc()`s.

```c
char* suffixChar_forEach (const char* src, const int slen, const char target, const char suffix) {

    int tgt_count = 0;
    for (int ci = 0; ci < slen; ++ci)
        if (target == src[ci])
            ++tgt_count;

    char* nText = malloc (slen + tgt_count + 1);
    if (!nText) {
        perror ("suffixChar_forEach-malloc"); return NULL;
    }
    int nlen = 0;
    for (int ci = 0; ci < slen; ++ci) {
        nText[nlen++] = src[ci];
        if (target == src[ci])
            nText[nlen++] = suffix;
        }
    nText[nlen] = '\0';

    printf ("\nNew text is: [%s]\n", nText);
    return nText;
}
```

- You can also, make the function generic to `suffix` a char after any given `target` character.
- You may also want to get the `strlen(nText)` from function if necessary.
- Same function can be used to suffix any char say '`-`'(hyphen) instead of just ' ' (space) :

```c
int main () {
    char str[] = ",.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,;kl;klkl.,.,.,.,.,.";
    printf ("\nInput: [%s]\n", str);

    char* result = suffixChar_forEach(str, strlen(str), ',', '-');
    if (!result) {
        printf ("ERROR: processing string\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("\nResult: [%s]\n", result);
    free (result);
    return 0;
}
```